# React navigation structure

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

Hi react developers I have an issue with a react-navigation structure, this happens when we nested navigators, in the doc of react-navigation says it is better to reduce the number of nested navigators, so I want to show an example of an e-commerce app that needs to render the One product screen in all navigation route.

[image: Case 1]

*"The initial route of the tab navigator is the first stack navigator and this has the initial route home screen*"

so as you can see in this diagram, the tab drawer and stack navigators are combined, this is in my opinion the most inefficient way to do this, I think is to create two stack navigators for the tab navigator, and in this stack, we are duplicating the one product screen.

*"We need to push the one product screen in the home screen and in the product section, this is why we put the product screen inside the stack navigator otherwise it will throw an error"*

Now, it is possible to do react memoize or pure components, but we still are creating two stack navigators. Now, this is the way I see in some blogs people do this navigation, but I think there is a better way to do this.

[image: Case 2]

This is the way I think is most efficient, we delete the stack navigator of the tabs and put only the screens to render, and in the drawer, we add a stack navigator that contains the screens we need to push.

Now my question is, it is possible to push the one product screen on the home screen and if is needed on the search screen too? and what is the best structure for making something like this *"By something like this I mean to use the one product screen in all screens to push and show to the user"*, and don't have performance issues by putting a lot of nested navigators, I want to avoid unnecessary re-renders of the screens and the components?

it is better for the first case or the second one?

Comment: This is a really well-written post for a new contributor. Thank you! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: The structure is good, you're not nesting more than you need to. But having both drawer and tabs might be confusing UX-wise.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Case 2 is better because you are not duplicating screens unnecessarily.

Before thinking about the React Navigation structure to be defined, it can be useful to map out the surface-level pages of the application to get a global view of the navigation system throughout the app.

Ex:
[image: Example of a surface-level map of screens]

Immediately this map provides valuable insight into the root of a number of possible usability weaknesses.

Also, it makes clear all the relationships between screens and the possible user flows between them (from which screen you have to navigate from/to).

After that, a React Navigation Structure could be proposed, considering the uniqueness of the screens. That way navigating between nested stacks/drawers/tabs becomes a simple coding effort, not an architectural one.